# LDAP config for Novell export

Tags: networking, ldap, authentication, opensuse, novell

I am trying to export the email userlist from groupwise via the consoleOne export tool..
In the tool, they ask for some basic LDAP parameters that make little sense in the GUI (I dislike GUIs).  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iBbT.png
I can't tell if MidlandCollege is stored as the ou or the dn.
The export process locks when declaring it is domain name/dn which should be correct.
ou hangs too.
What LDAP parameter am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking for, but...

```
o=MidlandCollege
```

looks ok so far.

To have more fun with the eDirectory, I strongly advise to having a look at Apache DirectoryStudio. It's a GUI, but you'll see the LDAP calls, so you can derive some more knowledge from this.

Answer (score -1):

you are in o=Mindlandcollege

ConsoleOne is deprecated at this point for any function and the export tool was never all that, iManager is the current tool from Novell. That being said, I would use Apache Directory Studio as it talks directly to the LDAP and has a more easily understandable toolset. Save consoleone and imanager for actually manipulating the edir objects.

I would use the search function in ADS to return objectclass=inetorgperson with the attributes you want, (CN and mail would be the most basic) have it dump to an xls/csv spreadsheet locally and manipulate from there